# What's the advantage of using ExecutorService with immediate get()?

Tags: java, executorservice

I see in the code here a lot of

```
executorService.submit(() -> {
    // do stuff
}).get();
```

...and I wonder why is the executorService used like this, submitting something you will immediately get?

Comment: Can't think of any advantage. The semantics of any exception thrown by the `do stuff` code will be different. That's the only tangible difference I can think of, and it seems unlikely anyone would choose it for that purpose and not leave a comment explaining it. I would say 90+% of the time, when you see code that makes you think "*why the hell would anyone do that?*" it's not because they're so smart that you can't understand it, it's that they're too stupid to know what they're doing.

Comment: One possible reason is that the executor is a way to manage a number of tasks from a central point. In other words, calling `executor.shutdownNow()` will cancel all tasks managed by that executor.

Comment: Imagine a module in your app that has several long running functions. If you execute them that way, and the user closes the module, you can shutdownNow the executor and all the tasks that were running in the module get cancelled. Obviously, I know nothing of your setup and it could well be a piece of useless code.

Comment: Consider rolling that edit back (except for the part in the body). The tag was useful, and the old title was better. This new tittle makes the entire post "Opinion based".

Answer (score 6):

Calling an immediate `get()` forces the `ExecutorService` to process "do stuff" in the executor service's threadpool rather than the local thread, which may for example choke processing if the maximum number of threads allocated to it is small, despite there being a great many threads running to handle requests.

Consider an obvious example of an executor service that has only 1 thread:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

and the example code being called from say an `HttpRequestHandler`.

By using the immediate `get()` processing of "do stuff" will be *serialized*, which may be desirable or a requirement, despite there being many simultaneous requests being processed each in their own thread.

Without the wrapper of `executorService.submit(...).get()`, processing of "do stuff" would be done in parallel in the request handler's thread, which may be fine or may cause problems if "do stuff" is particularly expensive or constrained in some way if parallelism is unbounded.

Parallelism can be limited/bounded instead of eliminated as follows:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
```

would limit processing to (for example) a maximum of 3 concurrently processing "do stuff"s, despite there being a great many requests being processed simultaneously.

---

Other more subtle effects are possible to via the choice of `Thread` in which "do stuff" runs. Consider:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(myThreadFactory);
```

will make "do stuff" run in a custom type of thread, rather than in the thread type chosen for the `HttpRequestHandler`.

Answer (score 3):

> submitting something you will immediately get

Just because you submit the task and 'get' it immediately, that doesn't necessarily mean it will be run immediately by the ExecutorService.

Here's a practical example of how this is useful:

You have a web server, which returns weather data. When an HTTP request comes in, you need to make a connection to a weather API to retrieve the weather data.

However, that weather API only allows two concurrent connections.

One way to solve this problem would be to have an ExecutorService with only two available threads.

Now, no matter how many servlet threads simultaneously submit tasks for execution, you can ensure that only two threads at a time can perform requests against the weather API. The servlet threads will block until the weather API is available to provide the servlet with the requested data.

Comment: While true, using a `Semaphore` instead is arguably a better way to achieve the same.

Comment: @michid I agree. Therefore, it's more of a slam dunk to use an ExecutorService if it does something slightly more clever, such as prioritising certain tasks if they will be less resource intensive to execute than others.

Answer (score 2):

Because somebody blindly copied this from [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit(java.util.concurrent.Callable)), which reads "If you would like to immediately block waiting for a task, you can use constructions of the form `result = exec.submit(aCallable).get();`"

Apart from that and the slight difference in exception semantics that @Michael mentioned in his comment on the question, there is also a slight difference wrt. interrupting of threads: if `// do stuff` blocks uninterruptedly you would still be able to interrupt the blocking call to `Future.get` or cancel the future. Note though, this doesn't do anything to the thread running `// do stuff`. That thread would keep blocking, only your main thread becomes unblocked.

Answer (score 0):

The only use case that I can think of is when:

- code that calls it MUST return some result synchronously (i.e. it's implementing some sync api handling http request or whatnot)
- the executor that is called is a ForkJoinPool and the task submitted is the RecursiveTask that will internally fork. This way you could use more than one cpu to execute whole task.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `.get()` call on a `Future` allows one to abstract the details of how exactly one delivers the result. Excusing the length of the example, if one looks at the `.get()` method for the below class, one can see that to implement the same sort of timing mechanism in the calling thread would be an excessive amount of boilerplate code. By abstracting it, the calling thread will simply block indefinitely while the worker thread worries about the details of delivering on the promise of its `Future`

```java
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

class DecayingRetry<T> implements Future<T> {
    protected final ScheduledExecutorService executor;
    protected final Callable<T> callable;
    private final boolean isOwnExecutor;
    protected ScheduledFuture<?> future;
    @SuppressWarnings("OptionalUsedAsFieldOrParameterType")
    protected Optional<?> result;
    protected boolean isDone;
    protected boolean isCancelled;
    protected final ReentrantLock lock;
    private final double maxDelay;
    private double initialDelay;
    private final TimeUnit timeUnit;


    private DecayingRetry(ScheduledExecutorService executor,
                            boolean isOwnExecutor,
                            Callable<T> callable,
                            long initialDelay,
                            long maxDelay,
                            TimeUnit timeUnit) {
        this.isOwnExecutor = isOwnExecutor;
        lock = new ReentrantLock(true);
        lock.lock();
        this.executor = executor;
        this.callable = callable;
        isCancelled = false;
        isDone = false;
        if (maxDelay < 0) {
            this.maxDelay = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        } else {
            this.maxDelay = maxDelay;
        }
        lock.lock();
        this.initialDelay = (double) initialDelay;
        this.timeUnit = timeUnit;
        future = executor.schedule(this::delayLoop, initialDelay, timeUnit);

    }


    public static <T> T on(Callable<T> callable, long initialDelay, long maxDelay, TimeUnit timeUnit) throws Exception {
        try {
            return Optional.ofNullable(callable.call()).orElseThrow(IllegalStateException::new);
        } catch (IllegalStateException ignored) {
            try {
                return new DecayingRetry<>(Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(),
                                                      true,
                                                      callable,
                                                      initialDelay,
                                                      maxDelay,
                                                      timeUnit).get();
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(-1);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static <T> T on(Callable<T> callable,
                           ScheduledExecutorService executor,
                           long initialDelay,
                           long maxDelay,
                           TimeUnit timeUnit) throws Exception {
        try {
            return Optional.ofNullable(callable.call()).orElseThrow(IllegalStateException::new);
        } catch (IllegalStateException ignored) {
            try {
                return new DecayingRetry<>(executor,
                                                      false,
                                                      callable,
                                                      initialDelay,
                                                      maxDelay,
                                                      timeUnit).get();
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(-1);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    synchronized private void delayLoop() {
        if (isDone) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            result = Optional.ofNullable(callable.call());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            result = Optional.of(e);
            isDone = true;
            return;
        }
        if (!result.isPresent()) {
            if (initialDelay < maxDelay) {
                initialDelay *= 1.618033988749; //PHI
                initialDelay = Math.min(maxDelay, initialDelay);
            }
            future = executor.schedule(this::delayLoop, (long) initialDelay, timeUnit);
        } else {
            isDone = true;
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }


    public boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) {
        if (isDone) {
            return false;
        } else if (future.cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning)) {
            isCancelled = true;
            isDone = true;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCancelled() {
        return isCancelled;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isDone() {
        return isDone;
    }

    @Override
    @NotNull
    public T get() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        lock.lock();
        while (!isDone) { // lock acquired too early for some reason, so we allow the worker thread to grab it
            lock.unlock();
            lock.lock();
        }
        if (result.isPresent()) {
            if (result.get() instanceof Throwable) {
                throw new ExecutionException((Throwable) result.get());
            }
            if (isOwnExecutor) {
                executor.shutdown();
            }
            //noinspection unchecked
            return (T) result.get();
        }
        throw new ExecutionException(new IllegalStateException("Retry result was null"));
    }

    public T get(long timeout, @NotNull TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
        throw new ExecutionException(new IllegalStateException("Not implemented"));
    }

}
```